# Problem Running multiple timers in MS excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run multiple timers in different cells in MS excel. I want to stop the timer only on the selected active cell.

The problem is when I am starting the timer on another cell. The previous timer on a previously chosen cell automatically stops.

The program I have now starts the timer upon double clicking.

I am trying to run different timers on the different cells and I want to stop the timer on the selected cells only using macros.

Here is what I have done so far:
The functions have been assigned to macros.

For a clearer explanation, let's say I start the timer in Cell A1 by double clicking(as coded in my worksheet). Now, if I start the timer in Cell A2, then the timer in A1 stops, and the timer in A2 runs. I want to run both the timers and stop the timer on the cell I select only while the other should still run.

I am scratching my head as to how I should modify my code to achieve this.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Tick As Date, t As Date
Global myCell  As Range

Sub stopwatch()

    t = Time
    Call StartTimer

End Sub

Sub StartTimer()
    Tick = Time + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    myCell.Value = Format(Tick - t - TimeValue("00:00:01"), "hh:mm:ss")
    Application.OnTime Tick, "StartTimer"
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Tick, Procedure:="StartTimer", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

In  my Worksheet , I have this code to start the timer on double click:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Set myCell = Target
    StartTimer
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - using a Dictionary to track which cells have timers running.
Double-click a cell to start a timer there: double-click again to stop.

This code is all in the Sheet3 module (codename)

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim timers As Object 'cell addresses as keys and start times as values
Dim nextTime         'next run time

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ToggleTimer Target
    Cancel = True
End Sub

Sub ToggleTimer(Optional c As Range = Nothing)
    Dim addr As String, k, macro
    
    If timers Is Nothing Then Set timers = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    macro = Me.CodeName & ".ToggleTimer"
    On Error Resume Next 'cancel any running timer
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=nextTime, Procedure:=macro, Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not c Is Nothing Then  '? called from a cell double-click ?
        addr = c.Address(False, False)
        If timers.exists(addr) Then
            timers.Remove addr  ' timer was running - remove it
        Else
            timers(addr) = Now  ' timer was not running - add it
        End If
    End If
    If timers.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub 'no more timers
    
    For Each k In timers  'update timer(s)
        Me.Range(k).Value = Format(Now - timers(k), "hh:mm:ss")
    Next k
    
    'schedule next run
    nextTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Application.OnTime nextTime, Me.CodeName & ".ToggleTimer"
    Debug.Print Me.CodeName
End Sub
```

Comment: I copied all the code in the worksheet, but it is not working. I renamed the sheet to Sheet3 and the timer does not seem to start when I double click the cell.

Comment: Hi, I checked but  the time is not updating live.

Comment: Was working for me but I made a couple of changes above, to prevent multiple `OnTime`'s running at once, and to take care of the sheet codename automatically.